# EthernetClient: HTML table isn't being fully populated

Tags: ethernet

I have the following code below for an `EthernetClient` named `client`. It is supposed to print a 2 row, 9 column table. The headers are `ID` and `Name` and are the first cell in each row. The other columns are the associated data. The problem I am having is that it is only printing the first `ID` and then the rest of the cells for that row are blank. The names all get printed in the row below it without a problem. Why won't it print the other IDs?

Here is the ID array: `String ids[16] = {"00000", "00001", "00010", "00011", "00100", "00101", "00110", "00111", "01000", "01001", "01010", "01011", "01100", "01101", "01110", "01111"};`

```
client.println("<table cellpadding=5, border=1>");
client.println("<tr>");
client.println("<th>ID</th>");
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  client.print("<td>");
  client.print(ids[i]);
  client.println("</td>");
}
client.println("</tr>");
client.println("<tr>");
client.println("<th>Name</th>");
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   client.print("<td>");
   client.print(name[i]);
   client.println("</td>");
}
client.println("</tr>");
client.println("</table>");
```

Comment: Could you show the output your get? Preferably the raw "view-source" html output.

Comment: I tried your code, changing `client` to `Serial` and the output looked OK. It even rendered OK in my web browser.